# Springboot file write, packaged as a jar package

Tags: spring-boot, jar

I want to write a file on the server, and then the browser can access it. I wrote it like this before using the war package.

```
request.getServletContext().getRealPath("cost.xlsx");
```

I use this path to successfully write files to the webapp folder.

Now I want to use the jar package, I would like to ask how can I write to the static folder of the resources resource folder, so that the browser can access the file I wrote on the server.